# Facebook Like - displaying the correct image and content

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I have a website (not a FB app) that has a page of which I have added a "Like" button to, using the facebook like button generator.

I am having trouble specifying the exact image I want to share along with a specific content.

I have tried the Open Graph meta tags, but these seem to be ignored (possibly they are only for FB apps??)

I'm using the following code for the button:

```
 <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.MYURL" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>
```

The functionality itself is working. It will share the link onto FB but not using the content/image I would prefer.

What am I doing wrong?

---

Debug

```
{
"og_object": {
"type": "website", 
"updated_time": "2014-09-05T09:58:07+0000", 
"url": "https://www.MYURL", 
"id": "MYNUMBER"
}, 
"share": {
"comment_count": 0, 
"share_count": 0
}, 
"id": "https://www.MYURL"
}
```

Comment: No, OG tags are not only for apps. Go check your URL using https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer to see if you implemented them correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have had a check and the JSON i get back in the debug does not show me much. I have added it into the original message above.

Comment: Sorry, that was the wrong address, I meant to link to the debug tool: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug – that should tell you if there’s something wrong with or OG tags.

Comment: Ok, im getting some more info.. its saying there are some critical errors.

Facebook URL Facebook URLs cannot be crawled.

Missing Required Property The 'og:type' property is required, but not present.

But I do have these... :(

Comment: What’s the actual URL of your page?

Comment: its on an internal domain which im unable to post due to company policy.... one thing.. its on a subdomain as well.. not sure if that is a problem? as in https://www.SUBDOMAIN.MYDOMAIN.co.uk

Comment: Ok... I have some progress. Facebook cannot crawl my subdomains on our dev environments. Does anybody know a way to get that working? I just tried on production and the OG stuff is picked up, but its not a good way of testing before pushing new code live. :-/

Comment: Your content of course has to be publicly available via HTTP/HTTPS – if your subdomains are not resolvable via public DNS, or access is not possible from the outside, then of course the scraper can not pick up the data.

Comment: Got it working. It was being blocked. Thanks for your help!